# How to set variable in router to be picked up in SMTP transport

Tags: exim

In exim4, I have a **redirect** router which changes some headers, including the `From:` header.

My SMTP transport will DKIM-sign mail if the `dkim_domain`, `dkim_selector`, and `dkim_private_key` parameters are given. These come from a macros, e.g.  in the transport:

```
dkim_domain = DKIM_DOMAIN
```

where the `DKIM_DOMAIN` macro is defined as

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}
```

That's all 'normal'. But the problem is that my router is using `headers_add` to change the From header, but because of this:

> This means that references to header lines in string expansions in the transport’s configuration do not “see” the added header lines.
>
> [source - see `headers_add`](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-generic_options_for_routers.html)

the transport is always looking to the *original* From header, not the rewritten one.

How can I change the macro to somehow look for the domain in a way that the router could affect? I cannot even set a custom transport in the router because it's a redirect router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears (still testing) this can be done by adding `address_data` in the router like:

```
address_data = foo=bar my_dkim_domain=example.com
```

Then using a macro for `dkim_domain` like:

```
${extract{my_dkim_domain}{$address_data}{$value}{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}}
```